# match url pattern for router middleware

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to have **/settings** and **/:acct/settings** use the same router files, but load different acct data depending on the url param.

Currently, my app.js file sets the default acct (req.user.acct) for use in the router files, like so:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.acct = req.user.acct
}

const settings = require('./routes/settings'); //setings.js file
app.use('/settings', settings);

const reports = require('./routes/reports');  //reports.js file
app.use('/reports', reports);
```

Can I use middleware to detect if acct is defined in the url (**/acct_123**/settings), and set res.locals.acct to the matching acct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can have two app.use middleware functions for each router to do the matching, like so:

```
const settings = require('./routes/settings'); //setings.js file

app.use('/:acct?/settings',
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.params.acct == "acct_123"){
        res.locals.acct = {acct: data}
    } 
    next();
  },
  settings,
);

app.use('/settings', settings);
```

Or better yet, put both routes in an array, and write some middleware for reuse on ALL the routes.

```
function getAcctData(route){
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try{       
       if (req.params.acct == "acct_123"){
           //do some acct lookup 
           res.locals.acct = {acct: data}
       }
    }catch{
       return res.redirect(route);
    } 
    next();
  }
};

const settings = require('./routes/settings'); //settings.js file
app.use(['/:acct?/settings','/settings'], getAcctData('settings'), settings);

const reports = require('./routes/reports'); //reports.js file
app.use(['/:acct?/reports','/reports'], getAcctData('reports'), reports);
```